# Under what conditions does the FWC give the PITCH PITCH aural call-out on the A320?

Tags: airbus-a320, fwc

I wanted to find more detailed information about the PITCH PITCH aural call-out that the FWC gives out on the A320. However it is not listed in the FCOM. It would help alot to understand about this feature.

It would be really helpful for an official reference also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "PITCH, PITCH" synthetic voice is called out when

> "The aircraft pitch attitude is becoming excessive during flare an
>   landing."

This is an optional feature which airlines can install to avoid tail strike.

<sub>Source: ECAM Description, Indicating/Recording Systems, Aircraft Systems, A320 FCOM</sub>

Comment: I have read this but I wanted to find out more detailed information how the system works. I have modified the question accordingly. Thank you

Comment: @Jai there is no mention of how the system is implemented. However, under the "Normal Procedures" chapter, it mentions the Pilot Monitoring should announce "PITCH PITCH" `if the pitch attitude approaches the tail strike pitch limit indicator, or reaches 7.5°`. It is therefore reasonable to assume the automated callout is a digital implementation of the above.

Answer (score 1):

“PITCH,PITCH” is called out on excessive pitch attitude durring flare or excessive pitch rate (ie. FWC estimates that pitch att WILL be exceeded shortly).

This can cause an occasional spurious trigger when the pilot is a bit late&abrupt in his flare and triggers quick nose up defletion, even though he is arresting that pitch-up before it gets dangerous for a tail-strike (eg say 6deg), you might still get this warning, based on the pitch rate alone.

What is the exact pitch angle and pitch rate that will trigger this alert is anyone’s guess, as it is not present in any documentation that I have found. Suffice to say that a properly executed approach and flare will not trigger it, regardless of weather conditions. In my experience, only poor execution by the pilot will.